# How to set environment variables for plink.exe?

Tags: ssh, windows, environment-variables, bashrc, putty

[`plink`](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) is Windows executable, which connects by ssh and does some command on server side.

For example

```
plink myname@mycomputer ls
```

will show result of ls command, being executed in the home directory of myname.

Unfortunately, neither `~/.profile` nor `~/.bashrc` is executed.

What is contract for `ssh` connection and what defines, which variables are set and which ones are not? If I run

```
plink myname@mycomputer env
```

I see some variables like `HOME`, `PWD` and `LOGNAME` which are specific to the user. How to set other ones?

Neither of the following helped:

```
plink myname@mycomputer sh -c env

plink myname@mycomputer bash -c env
```

These commands worked, but showed "naked" set of variables.

How to tell shell to execute it's initial scripts for the user?

Comment: Try: `bash -ic env`

Comment: ... might need `-t` as well to force allocation of a tty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `ssh` runs can be observed with e.g. [`sysdig`](https://www.sysdig.org) in one terminal and then elsewhere running `plink myname@mycomputer uptime` which should show something like

```
$ sudo sysdig -p '%proc.cmdline' 'evt.type = execve'
sshd
bash -c uptime
bash -c uptime
uptime
```

so in this case `bash` is being run (this may not be the case for example on Alpine Linux which does not install `bash` by default) with the `-c uptime` arguments. This causes `bash` to more or less directly `exec` that command as there's no fancy pipeline or multiple shell commands that necessitate that `bash` continue to run.

Next, we can log what files `bash` opens, and again run the `plink ... uptime` command (this may be more verbose depending on what else is going on on the system):

```
$ sysdig 'evt.type = open and proc.name = "bash"'
7847 16:03:48.388447919 0 bash (22135) > open
7848 16:03:48.388466237 0 bash (22135) < open fd=3(<f>/etc/ld.so.cache) name=/etc/ld.so.cache flags=4097(O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) mode=0
7855 16:03:48.388669720 0 bash (22135) > open
7856 16:03:48.388695391 0 bash (22135) < open fd=3(<f>/lib64/libtinfo.so.5) name=/lib64/libtinfo.so.5 flags=4097(O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) mode=0
7871 16:03:48.389069345 0 bash (22135) > open
7872 16:03:48.389082901 0 bash (22135) < open fd=3(<f>/lib64/libdl.so.2) name=/lib64/libdl.so.2 flags=4097(O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) mode=0
7885 16:03:48.389284722 0 bash (22135) > open
7886 16:03:48.389290872 0 bash (22135) < open fd=3(<f>/lib64/libc.so.6) name=/lib64/libc.so.6 flags=4097(O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) mode=0
7921 16:03:48.391876315 0 bash (22135) > open
7922 16:03:48.391927051 0 bash (22135) < open fd=-6(ENXIO) name=/dev/tty flags=67(O_NONBLOCK|O_RDWR) mode=0
7945 16:03:48.393905761 0 bash (22135) > open
7946 16:03:48.393957884 0 bash (22135) < open fd=3(<f>/proc/meminfo) name=/proc/
meminfo flags=4097(O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) mode=0
8049 16:03:48.395910893 0 bash (22135) > open
8050 16:03:48.395916693 0 bash (22135) < open fd=3(<f>/root/.bashrc) name=/root/.bashrc flags=1(O_RDONLY) mode=0
```

So it appears `/root/.bashrc` here is being read on my test virt; to confirm this we can add something to that file and again run our test command, on the server:

```
echo echo echo >> ~/.bashrc
```

and then we connect again (adjust the command to be `plink ...` as necessary)

```
$ ssh gato uptime
echo
 16:05:20 up  5:19,  1 user,  load average: 0.11, 0.38, 0.27
$
```

so in this case `.bashrc` *is* being read, so you could put commands in there. I am not sure why in your case `.bashrc` is not being read; trace things to see what is going on.